# Is it possible to translate in-place after inapposite travel?

Tags: the-strange

When a creature travels via inapposite means (inapposite gate, harness, directly from the strange, etc), will end up out of context when the laws of the destination recursion differ, and will begin weakening (and possibly dying).

If this happens to a quickened individual, who has the ability to initiate translations between recursions, is it possible for that individual to initiate a translation to the recursion it is currently in to adapt to its context, without travelling?

As a concrete example, assume an player character with the Abides in Stone focus (that is, an actual golem) crashes through a one-way inapposite gate to Earth, which lacks the Magic law to allow a golem to function, which means that character would die within several days. Could this character now translate itself into the Earth context (meaning swapping the focus and becoming human, if not already so) without changing recursion? Or would they need to travel (by translation or inapposite) to another recursion, then translate to Earth from there to get back into context?

Answer (score -1):

I would personally answer "yes". Different GM's will give different answers.

But ... where do you wind up? Here I'd say you wind up where you last used translation to leave from, or the last place you were at in that world (might not be the same if you left via gate), or the default location if you never "stored" an address before.
i.e. -- you will probably NOT be in the same place after translating out.